# How to mention local drive path inside Latex?

Tags: paths

I'm trying to mention below path... but I am getting an error.

```
Select \textbf{root directory} and select the folder 
\textbf{Diagnostics_Example} from path \textit{C:\Users\harshalb\K-DCP 
Projects\OTX}
```

Please guide me as I'm new to Latex.

Comment: `C:/Users/harshalb/K-DCP Projects/OTX` is the file path you are looking for.

Comment: You should avoid spaces in file paths. Not because of LaTeX, it is not a LaTeX thing, because it is better style to avoid spaces.

Comment: @Johannes_B Yes it is

Comment: And write `Diagnostics\_Example` instead of `Diagnostics_Example` because `_` is a special TeX char.

Comment: @Johannes_B but there is no space in mentioned math

Comment: DCP<space>Projects?

Comment: @Johannes_B opps yes it is

thank you..let me try it agin

Answer (score 6):

I would strongly advise you to either use `\verb` or the `url` package.

The `\verb` command is designed for typesetting entities that include characters that are special in LaTeX and it respects spaces in its argument.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

Select \verb+root directory+ and select the folder
\verb+Diagnostics_Example+ from path
\verb+C:\Users\harshalb\K-DCP Projects\OTX+.

\end{document}
```

As you can see the syntax is slightly non-standard, writing

```
\verb+...+
```

where `+` can be replaced by any character not in the argument.

The disadvantage of `\verb` is that it will not allow its argument to break over lines.  The `url` package removes that restriction:

[image: Sample url output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[obeyspaces]{url}

\begin{document}

Select \url+root directory+ and select the folder
\url+Diagnostics_Example+ from a path on your system such as this one:
\url+C:\Users\harshalb\K-DCP Projects\OTX+.

\end{document}
```

Note the use of the `obeyspaces` option to respect spaces in the arguments.
The `url` package allows you to change the style/font of urls too, e.g. `\urlstyle{rm}` will use the text font.  See the package's documentation either via `texdoc url` on your system or at https://www.ctan.org/pkg/url?lang=en .

As @Mico mentions:

1. You may wish to consider adding the package options `hyphens` and/or `spaces` to allow line breaks at those characters.
2. The `url` package also provides the `\path` command, which is a version of `\url` which does *not* get converted to an active link if you have the `hyperef` package loaded.

Comment: +1. The `url` package also provides the macro `\path`, which essentially behaves like `\url` *except* that the macro's argument won't be made into a hyperlink in case the `hyperref` package is loaded as well. A separate comment: To allow linebreaks at hyphens and spaces, I'd also specify the options `hyphens` and `spaces` while loading the `url` package.

Comment: @Mico Indeed - answer extended.

Comment: @AndrewSwann thank you very much for ur valuable suggestion.